# restart mac finder sync extension using shell command

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, findersync

I have a cocoa application with finder sync extension. I want this extension to restart using shell command. Is it possible to restart the finder sync extension?

Answer (score 2):

I also searched for it:

```
killall Finder
```

It will restart your Finder and reload the extension.

To add/remove the extension to/from Finder:

```
pluginkit -r <path to your appex>
pluginkit -a <path to your appex>
```

But after removal from Finder you still have to stop the extension (by killing it, by exemple).